# Ограничить количество страниц в пагинации

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом ограничить пагинацию на странице.
На данный момент количество страниц выходит за рамки экрана. Как сделать, что бы было четкое представление информации

Имеется контроллер:

```
@GetMapping("/ondock")
public String ondockGet(Model model, Principal principal,
                        @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page) throws IOException, ParseException {
    Page<Cargo> cargos = cargoService.cargoOndockPage(PageRequest.of(page, 10));
    model.addAttribute("cargos", cargos);
    model.addAttribute("numbers", IntStream.range(0, cargos.getTotalPages()).toArray());
    return "ondock";
}
```

и HTML кусок:

```
        <ul class="pagination" th:if="${cargos.totalPages > 0}">
        <li th:each="pageNumber : ${numbers}"
            th:class="${pageNumber == cargos.number} ? active">
            <a th:href="@{'/ondock?page=' + ${pageNumber}}" th:text="${pageNumber + 1}"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, нужно скрывать какие-то номера страниц)

Возможно, проще это будет сделать через стили, возможно, например, так:

```
if(cargos.getTotalPages() > 10) {
    model.addAttribute("numbers", 
        IntStream.range(
            page > 5 ? (page - 5) : 0, 
            (cargos.getTotalPages() - page) > 5 ? (page + 5) : cargos.getTotalPages()
        ).toArray());
}
else {
    model.addAttribute("numbers", IntStream.range(0, cargos.getTotalPages()).toArray());
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ :)